# Cocos2D - ccTouchesBegan not registering

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have ccTouchesBegan to listen to touch events.
It listen fine except within the location where the status bar is usually at (i.e the one that contains battery life, time etc), even though the status bar is turned off.

In my case, the top 20px of my app isn't causing ccTouchesBegan to get triggered.

How can I ensure that touch event is still being fired even at that location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Turn out it's just a simulator issue.
It works fine on the device.

Thanks,
Tee